# How do I run Oracle plsql procedure from Lisp?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, lisp, clojure

How do I get started?

Comment: Check this out
http://www.franz.com/support/documentation/6.2/doc/oracle-interface.htm

Comment: You may want to read [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123234/what-is-the-best-sql-libary-for-use-in-lisp) too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the easiest way to achieve this by using Clojure.
Here is the example code:

```
(ns example
  (:require [clojure.contrib.sql :as sql])
  (:import  [java.sql Types]))
```

(def devdb {:classname "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            :subprotocol "oracle"
            :subname "thin:username/password@localhost:1509:devdb"
            :create true})

(defn exec-ora-stored-proc [input-param db callback]
  (sql/with-connection db
    (with-open [stmt (.prepareCall (sql/connection) "{call some_schema.some_package.test_proc(?, ?, ?)}")]
      (doto stmt
        (.setInt               1 input-param)
        (.registerOutParameter 2 Types/INTEGER)
        (.registerOutParameter 3 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes/CURSOR)
        (.execute))
      (callback (. stmt getInt 2) (. stmt getObject 3)))))

(exec-ora-stored-proc
 123 ;;input param value
 devdb
 (fn [err-code res-cursor]
   (println (str "ret_code: " err-code))
   ;; prints returned refcursor rows
   (let [resultset (resultset-seq res-cursor)]
     (doseq [rec resultset]
       (println rec)))))

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an interface to the Oracle SQL database. As Bob pointed out, Allegro CL has such an interface.

[GNU CLISP apparently comes with an interface to the database as well.](http://clisp.cons.org/impnotes/oracle.html)

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to do Oracle stuff from your Common Lisp program is to use [CLSQL](http://clsql.b9.com/).  There are plenty of other packages for doing stuff with databases from Common Lisp.  Have a look at [Cliki's database page](http://www.cliki.net/database)