# What is the best SQL library for use in Common Lisp?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, lisp, common-lisp

Ideally something that will work with Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL and Posgress.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you mean common lisp by lisp, then there's **[cl-rdbms](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-rdbms/)**. it is heavily tested on postgres (uses [postmodern](http://common-lisp.net/project/postmodern/) as the backend lib), it has a toy sqlite backend and it also has an OCI based oracle backend. it supports abstracting away the different sql dialects, has an sql quasi-quote syntax extension installable on e.g. the [] characters.

i'm not sure if it's the best, and i'm biased anyway... :) but we ended up rolling our own lib after using [clsql](http://clsql.b9.com/) for a while, which is i think the most widely used sql lib for cl.

see [cliki page about sql](http://www.cliki.net/SQL) for a further reference.

Answer (score 8):

At the moment there's no open-source library that supports all the SQL backends you mention. [CLSQL](http://clsql.b9.com/) comes quite close (lacking only support for MS SQL). The alternatives are:

- [CL-RDBMS](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-rdbms/) (which supports Oracle, Postgres through Postmodern and SQLite3)
- [Postmodern](http://common-lisp.net/project/postmodern/) (only Postgres).

If you can use a commercial Lisp, you can give a try to [CommonSQL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/sql-tutorial/index.html) included with Lispworks, which supports all the databases you mentioned.

CLSQL looks like the most popular open source library at the moment. Unfortunately, it seems to suffer from bit rot, and the developers had to make some compromises to support all those platforms.

If the RDB backend is not a constraint, then I recommend Postmodern. It is very well documented and has a clean API (and a nice small language compiled to SQL). Also, it is well maintained and small enough to keep being understandable and extensible. It focuses only on Postgres, not trying to be all things for all people.

Comment: it's wrong. see http://www.cliki.net/SQL

Comment: I guess you were right. But if CLSQL supported MS SQL *I* would be right :-) Anyway, I edited my answer.

Comment: Isn't MS SQL reachable by ODBC? CL-SQL is supposed to support ODBC.

Comment: They don't say anything about MS SQL in CLSQL's documentation.

Comment: CLSQL definitely communicates with MSSQL over ODBC just fine (better than plain-ODBC in my limited experience)

Answer (score 2):

Allegro Common Lisp has an [ODBC](http://www.franz.com/support/documentation/8.1/doc/aodbc.htm) library and a [MySQL-specific](http://franz.com/support/documentation/8.1/doc/mysql.htm) library, both exhaustively documented. I've used the MySQL one; no surprises.